# How to stop calculation of a Shiny app while a Drop Down Button is open?

Tags: html, css, r, shiny, dropdown

I'm developping a Shiny app to filter a database (like Excel), and I'd like to stop all the calculation of the app when a Drop Down Button is open. Do you know how could I do that please ? It's my first Shiny app, so I'm pretty sure that I made some silly mistakes.

In my Drop Down Button, I have a CheckBoxGroupInput, with the different choices for one variable of my database. Problem : I have to wait a few seconds between each selection inside the CheckBoxGroupInput, because the app is refreshing for each additionnal choice in the CheckBox.

An example for one variable :

**ui :**

```
dropdownButton(
                 label = "Country :", status = "default", width = 200, circle = FALSE,
                 actionButton(inputId = "country_all", label = "(Un)select all"),
                 uiOutput("countrybis")
               ),
               verbatimTextOutput(outputId = "country_print")
```

**server :**

*Function for refreshing each list in the different CheckBox :*

```
Function_List_Data <- function(p_type, p_processchoice, p_year, p_variable, p_product, p_country,
                                 p_item, p_season, p_region, p_calcamp){
    if(p_processchoice == "GROSSVAR"){
      data <- dataset_var[YEARBIS >= p_year[1] & YEARBIS <= p_year[2],]}
    else if(p_processchoice == "YIELD"){
      data <- dataset_rdt[YEARBIS >= p_year[1] & YEARBIS <= p_year[2],]}
    else{data <- dataset[YEARBIS >= p_year[1] & YEARBIS <= p_year[2],]}
    if (p_region == 2) {data <- data[REGION %in% list("EU-15","EU-27","EU-28")]}
    else if (p_region == 3) {data <- data[REGION %in% list("C.I.S.")]}
    if (p_calcamp == 2) {data <- data[`CAMPAIGN/CALENDAR` == "CAMPAIGN",]}
    else if (p_calcamp == 3) {data <- data[`CAMPAIGN/CALENDAR` == "CALENDAR",]}
    else if (p_calcamp == 4) {data <- data[`CAMPAIGN/CALENDAR` == "OTHERS",]}
    if (!is.null(p_variable)) {data <- data[VARIABLE %in% p_variable]}
    if (!is.null(p_product)) {data <- data[PRODUCT %in% p_product,]}
    if (!is.null(p_country)) {data <- data[COUNTRY %in% p_country,]}
    if (!is.null(p_item)) {data <- data[ITEM %in% p_item,]}
    if (!is.null(p_season)) {data <- data[SEASON %in% p_season,]}
    if(nrow(data)<1){ data <- data[1,] }
    if (p_type == "VARIABLE"){List <- unique(unlist(data$VARIABLE), use.names = FALSE)}
    else if (p_type == "PRODUCT"){List <- unique(unlist(data$PRODUCT), use.names = FALSE)}
    else if (p_type == "COUNTRY"){List <- unique(unlist(data$COUNTRY), use.names = FALSE)}
    else if (p_type == "ITEM"){List <- unique(unlist(data$ITEM), use.names = FALSE)}
    else if (p_type == "SEASON"){List <- unique(unlist(data$SEASON), use.names = FALSE)}
    return(List)
  }
```

*Calculation for the Country column :*

```
   Country_List <- reactive({
    Function_List_Data(p_type = "COUNTRY",
                       p_processchoice = input$dataprocess_choice,
                       p_year = input$year,
                       p_variable = input$variable_list,
                       p_product = input$product_list,
                       p_country = NULL,
                       p_item = input$item_list,
                       p_season = input$season_list,
                       p_region = input$region,
                       p_calcamp = input$campaign_calendar)})
  observeEvent(input$country_all, {
    if (is.null(input$country_list)) {
      updateCheckboxGroupInput(session = session, inputId = "country_list", selected = Country_List())}
    else {updateCheckboxGroupInput(session = session, inputId = "country_list", selected = "")}
  })
  output$country_print <- renderPrint({
    if(is.null(input$country_list)){"- ALL -"}
    else{as.matrix(input$country_list)}
  })
  output$countrybis <- renderUI({
    checkboxGroupInput(inputId = "country_list", label = "Choose", choices = sort(Country_List()), selected = input$country_list)
  })
```

**EDIT : 
When I calculate the Country_List only when I click on the DropdownButton, it's not working, you can see the error on the screen :**

[Error received : the Country_List is calculate after the CheckBox is print](https://i.stack.imgur.com/k75cQ.png) 
.

Button Select All / Unselect All :

```
observeEvent(input$country_all, {
Country_List <- Function_List_Data(p_type = "COUNTRY",
                     p_processchoice = input$dataprocess_choice,
                     p_year = input$year,
                     p_variable = input$variable_list,
                     p_product = input$product_list,
                     p_country = NULL,
                     p_item = input$item_list,
                     p_season = input$season_list,
                     p_region = input$region,
                     p_calcamp = input$campaign_calendar)
if (is.null(input$country_list)) {
  updateCheckboxGroupInput(session = session, inputId = "country_list", selected = Country_List)}
else {updateCheckboxGroupInput(session = session, inputId = "country_list", selected = "")}})
```

RenderPrint :

```
output$country_print <- renderPrint({
if(is.null(input$country_list)){"- ALL -"}
else{as.matrix(input$country_list)}})
```

CheckBox :

```
output$countrybis <- renderUI({
observeEvent(input$Country_DropDown,{
  print("bla")
  Country_List <- Function_List_Data(p_type = "COUNTRY",
                       p_processchoice = input$dataprocess_choice,
                       p_year = input$year,
                       p_variable = input$variable_list,
                       p_product = input$product_list,
                       p_country = NULL,
                       p_item = input$item_list,
                       p_season = input$season_list,
                       p_region = input$region,
                       p_calcamp = input$campaign_calendar)
})
checkboxGroupInput(inputId = "country_list", label = "Choose", choices = sort(Country_List), selected = input$country_list) })
```

Comment: If you have a way to know whether the dropdown list is open or closed (let's imagine as a function `dropdown_is_open`) then you can use `validate(need(!dropdown_is_open(), "Waiting for dropdown"))` at the beginning of your reactive to prevent evaluation until the dropdown is closed. See `?validate`. Just half an answer so I'll leave it as a comment :)

Comment: Hello Antoine, thank you for your answer. I tried something like that : I used ObserveEvent or "onclick" (shinyjs package) : I can't know when the list is open, but I know when I click on the dropdown button. So when I click on the dropdown button, I run the function to generate the list, but it doesn't work (vector coerce something..). I will send my code tomorrow morning to show you this.

Comment: I edited my first post to show you how I changed the code.

Comment: Sorry but we misunderstood ourselves : actually I don't have a solution for my problem, it appears that R generates the Country_List after the Checkbox is generated, whereas the "ObserveEvent" is written before the creation of the CheckBox. Do you have any idea please ?

Comment: Sorry I got confused with another thread where the poster had actually found an answer --'

Comment: No problem. Do you have any idea how I could generate the Country List before the CheckBox is printed ?

Comment: As a side note, your dropdown menu could be replaced by a more standard `pickerInput` from `shinyWidget`. See a live demo of `pickerInput` at `http://shinyapps.dreamrs.fr/shinyWidgets/ `. It supports "select/deselect all" and "live search" out of the box if you pass the relevant parameters.

Comment: The simplest way I see to achieve what you want is to use an action button to launch the search. This lets your users select all they want, then click on "go" or "search" or whatever and get the results. This is a standard feature of shiny. Basically you add an actionButton (let's say `id=button_go`) and then use an `eventReactive` (with `input$button_go` as event) instead of a `reactive` for your data table. This ensures the table is evaluated everytime `button_go` is clicked and only then. See `?eventReactive`. Hope that helps!

Comment: The PickerInput is exactly what I was looking for ! Thank you very much Antoine ! I'll try that soon and also try to stop the generation of the Country List after each click. I can't generate the list like that, because there are several Boxes to select, and then eventually I could use a submit button to launch the RenderDT. But I really need the List to be generated automatically. The selection on CheckBox 1 will modify the list on CheckBox 2, and conversely...

Comment: For your "search" button, don't forget you can easily include icons using for example `icon("search")`. This inserts the [corresponding font-awesome icon](https://fontawesome.com/v4.7.0/icons/). Have fun!

Comment: I'm gonna love it ! Little question about that : do you know if I can hide the panel that print the selected data ? I don't like the "inline" display, I prefer to display the selected data in one column, by using as.matrix for example.

Comment: Sorry I am not sure what you mean about the inline display of the panel. But if you know some css you can do pretty much anything. Write a css file that does the changes you want and inject it with `includeCss`. See https://shiny.rstudio.com/articles/css.html

Comment: @antoine-sac I wanted to hide the selected choices from the button, but it's alright I found the solution : `selected-text-format`= "static"  . But do you know how can I limit the number of choices displayed ? My list is really big and it takes all my screen. Also, do you know how can I add an icon just for the live-search section ?

Comment: And another thing, do you know how to center my static text inside the button ? Thank you again @antoine-sac

Comment: There is an argument you can pass in the pickerInput options to display the list as a shorter scrollable list, it is one of the examples in the shinywidgets demo. Don't know for the live search, I am not sure how you'd edit that. To center the text you need to apply some CSS via the argument `style="CSS code to center"` which you can pass to any tags. The CSS should be something like `"text-align: center"`. Or you can define some CSS at global level and target your list elements with `".dropdown > ul > li {text-align: center} " `

Comment: My bad, I misread the PickerInput Options description for the size. However, I can't center the text (sorry but I really begin with CSS). Thanks again @antoine-sac